# Seeking datasets to construct minimal reproducible examples for ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, data

I would like to construct a minimal reproducible example to illustrate a question here on GIS SE. Ideally, that example would reference data that's easily accessible to any ArcGIS user, without requiring that they download data from some external site.

Are there example feature classes (and/or data of other types) that I can rely on every user having access to as part of their ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap) installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ArcGIS for Desktop comes with template data inside a file geodatabase.  The data are located, on a typical installation, under:

C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\TemplateData\TemplateData.gdb

It containst two feature datasets, one for the US (in NAD83) and one for the World (in WGS84).

Additionally you have the [Esri Data and Maps DVD](http://www.esri.com/data/data-maps/), which the data content can also be downloaded [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?owner=esri&title=ESRI%20Data%20&%20Maps&content=all) from ArcGIS Online.

Comment: Terrific! Thanks. That `TemplateData.gdb` is exactly what I was looking for. Regarding the Esri Data and Maps DVD, do you know whether it contains the datasets that get used by the arcpy code snippets that are scattered throughout the ArcGIS Help Library (typically near the bottom of each page)?

Comment: I don't believe so...  To my understanding those code snippets are created ad-hoc.  The Esri Data and Maps provide large dataset some of it is found in the ArcGIS Online basemap (e.g. Topo and Streetmap).

Comment: OK. Good to know I haven't been missing something obvious. It's really quite a pity that they haven't taken the time to make those code snippets reproducible. That is the tradition, for example, for all code samples included in help files in my native **R** language, and it's a super-helpful way to present ... help.