# Seeking dataset to create reproducible ArcPy example for ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, data, arcgis-pro

I would like to create a reproducible example for ArcPy (for ArcGIS Pro) and cannot locate any example feature classes or rasters that come with installation.

I am looking for something like the TemplateData.gdb that came with ArcGIS for Desktop as answered at [Seeking datasets to construct minimal reproducible examples for ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98459).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using ArcPy, instead of using larger/complex datasets (that may have characteristics that are not obvious to anyone not frequently using them), whenever I create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers) I try to generate the test data as part of it.

I am including below some test code that I used to develop an eLearning lecture named "Creating Fishnet Feature Classes for Testing" in the [ArcPy for Python Developers using ArcGIS Pro](https://www.udemy.com/course/arcpy-for-python-developers/?referralCode=100C9E0D76D93E937B22) course at Udemy.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
if not arcpy.Exists(r"C:\Temp\test.gdb"):
    arcpy.management.CreateFileGDB(r"C:\Temp","test.gdb")
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\Test.gdb"
srWGS84 = arcpy.SpatialReference("WGS 1984")
arcpy.management.CreateFishnet("FishnetLines",
                               "0 0", "0 1", 1, 1, 10, 15, None,
                               "LABELS", "DEFAULT", "POLYLINE")
if arcpy.Exists("FishnetPoints"):
    arcpy.management.Delete("FishnetPoints")
arcpy.management.Rename("FishnetLines_label","FishnetPoints")
arcpy.management.CreateFishnet("FishnetPolys",
                               "0 0", "0 1", 1, 1, 4, 6, None,
                               "NO_LABELS", "DEFAULT", "POLYGON")
for geomType in ["Polys","Lines","Points"]:
    arcpy.management.DefineProjection(
        "Fishnet{0}".format(geomType),srWGS84)
print("\n{0} now contains three test feature classes!".format(
    r"C:\Temp\test.gdb"))
```

The code will create test point, line and polygon feature classes.  If you need more/less features than this code creates just change the sixth and seventh Create Fishnet parameter values.

The same code should work equally well with ArcMap.

**Disclosure**: I am the developer and presenter of the course mentioned above.